# Double Linked list and using a reverse search

Tags: c++, list

Ok Ive never used lists at all but Ill do my best to explain what im trying to do.

---

```
struct node {
 node(int value=0) { data=value; next=prev=this; }
 int data;
 node *next;
 node *prev;
};

class list {
 public:
 list(int N=0, int value=0);
 ˜list();
 bool empty() const { return N == 0; }
 bool full() const { return false; }
 int size() const { return N; }
 void resize(int);
 void clear();
 void insert(int, const int &);
 void remove(int);
 void push_back(const int &din) { insert(N, din); }
 void pop_back() { remove(N-1); }
 const int & back();
 int & operator[](int);
 private:
 int N;
 node *head;
 node *findnode(int);
}

_________________________________________
inline
node *list::findnode(int i) {
 if (i == -1)
 return head;
 node *p = head->next; 
 while (i--)
 p = p->next;
 return p;
}
```

I am supposed to rewrite the `findnode()` function to do a forward search when `i<(N/2)` and do a reverse search when `i>(N/2)`. Ive tried but I keep getting segmentation errors. I think I just dont exactly get whats going on. All the other functions listed in the list class are correctly written.

Ive corrected my Node struct. Sorry ahead of time im very lost when it comes to these object pointers and whats really going on. Here's what I tried.

```
 97 inline
 98 node *list::findnode(int i) {
 99         if (i == -1)
100                 return head;
101 
102         if (i < N/2){
103                 node *p = head->next;
104                 while (i--)
105                         p = p->next;
106 
107                 return p;
108         }
109 
110 
111         if (i > N/2){
112                 node *p = head->prev;
113 
114                 i =( i - N/2 );
115                 while (i--)
116                         p = p->prev;
117 
118                 return p;
119         }
120 }
```

Comment: You'll have a hard time getting a doubly-linked list working with only a `next` pointer...

Comment: Sorry I posted my node struct incorrectly. Its actually

----------------------------------------------------------------
struct node {
 node(int value=0) { data=value; next=prev=this; }
 int data;
 node *next;
 node *prev;
};

____________________________________________________

Answer (score 0):

I won't give the full answer. But essentially use an if-else to split between your two cases. In the first case search forwards like above. In the second case search in reverse. But in order to do this you should augment your node class to have a prev member, to make it actually a doubly linked list. Have the list store the tail of the list. You'll have to modify most of your list functions to accomplish this.

```
inline
node *list::findnode(int i) {
 if(i < size()/2) {
   //search from beginning of list
 }
 else {
   //search from end of list by starting at tail
   node *p = tail;
   i = i-size/2;
   while(i--) {
     p = p->prev;
   }
   return p;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. sorry my node structure actually looks like this.

----------------------------------------------------------------
struct node {
 node(int value=0) { data=value; next=prev=this; }
 int data;
 node *next;
 node *prev;
};

is there a way to do it without actually creating a tail node. I would but the assignment was just to rewrite the findnode function.

Thanks for not giving me the straight answer, I do want to learn this ive just kind of gotten stuck having never dealt much with pointers in general.

Comment: I don't think so based on how you stated the question, but to get the tail node, you just search for a node whose "next" is null. Then you will have a tail.